# Network is unreachable error - Virtualbox (Mininet Ubuntu Image)

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have been using Virtualbox to run mininet simulations. I have two adapters, eth0 uses NAT and has the IP address 192.168.56.1 and eth1 is a host only adapter. I can SSH into the VM using 192.168.56.1, however when I try to reach anything external to the network from the VM (for example cloning a git repository), I get the message network unreachable. I have tried pinging IP addresses directly to check that it is not a DNS issue. Why can I not reach the internet? I understand that a common issue is that an IP address has not been assigned to one of the adapters, but here eth0 quite clearly has an IP address.

ifconfig -a:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:ef:9b:c8  
          inet addr:192.168.56.101  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:235 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:164 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:25042 (25.0 KB)  TX bytes:23566 (23.5 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:76:c7:9a  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:432 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:432 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:34376 (34.3 KB)  TX bytes:34376 (34.3 KB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox's  "Host-only" adaptors specifically don't allow internet access:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes

> Host-only networking
>
> This can be used to create a network containing the host and a set of virtual machines, without the need for the host's physical network
>   interface. Instead, a virtual network interface (similar to a loopback
>   interface) is created on the host, providing connectivity among
>   virtual machines and the host.

Check the table at the end of the 6.2 section to see which types of adaptors do what you actually want them to do (hint: probably one of Bridged, NAT or NAT-Network).

I'd try disabling your host-only adaptor and see if that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: When I disable the host-only adapter it does work. Any idea how to allow internet access whilst also having a host-only adapter enabled? And just to be clear - I had both a NAT adapter and a host-only adapter enabled originally. I would like the host-only adapter for the mininet simulation and the NAT adapter for internet access to Github etc.

Comment: I think you're missing something here - as in you are trying to do something host-only specifically WILL NOT DO. Host-only gives you communication between VM's and host, that's it. You want the other options on that page, so you need to go look at that chart I mentioned and figure out what adaptor you really wanted.